# The child node "firewall_name" at path "hwi_oauth" must be configured

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm doing a project with Symfony2 and I want to use Google/Facebook/Twitter for connection. So I installed HWIOAuthBundle, but I got this error when I update my composer.json

> "The child node "firewall_name" at path "hwi_oauth" must be
>   configured.".

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, and if you read the doc :**

*(it gives the config... )*

[Step 2: Configuring resource owners](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-configuring_resource_owners.md#step-2-configuring-resource-owners)

> HWIOAuthBundle creates a dedicated service for each resource owner you
>   want to use in your application. These resource owners will be used in
>   the oauth firewall. The bundle ships several pre-configured resource
>   owners that need only a little configuration.
>
> To make this bundle work you need to add the following to your
>   app/config/config.yml:
>
> ## app/config/config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_name: secured_area

    # an optional setting to configure a query string parameter which can be used to redirect
    # the user after authentication, e.g. /connect/facebook?_destination=/my/destination will
    # redirect the user to /my/destination after facebook authenticates them.  If this is not
    # set then the user will be redirected to the original resource that they requested, or
    # the base address if no resource was requested.  This is similar to the behaviour of
    # [target_path_parameter for form login](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/form_login.html).
    # target_path_parameter: _destination
```